# Long (Pole/Poll/Pull)?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, homonyms

When you're indicating that something is the critical path that causes the whole project to take a long time, which one is it?

1. Long Pole
2. Long Poll
3. Long Pull

I actually find various sources when I look it up on google that contradict each other.

- https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/a-long-pull
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080805-00/?p=21373

Comment: There seem to be two different expressions, each used as metaphors. _Long pull / haul_ = a lengthy, difficult journey, as for instance by portageurs (to avoid rapids), or to get over a range of hills. 'Long pole [in a tent]' = the round peg in the square hole, causing problems, holding up the job.

Comment: But typically in the sense of a schedule item it's the long pole [in the tent] as Edward says.

Comment: I don't think ***pull*** here ever had any currency in BrE (the others look like mistranscriptions of a relatively unfamiliar usage). But even in AmE this particular metaphoric usage has been completely overshadowed by ***a long haul*** for at least half a century.

Comment: I've heard and read it as _long pull_. The image is railroady, with a little engine that could if necessary. Note that _haul_ and _pull_ are synonymous.

Comment: I've never heard long pull or long pole (and I think long poll is not correct) is everyday use, but I've heard long haul meaning an arduous process that the participants are aware of when they start it.

Answer (score 2):

It's "the long pole." As Edwin and Jim commented, it's short for "the long pole in the tent."

The New York Times printed [an opinion piece](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/01/06/opinion/06iht-edsafire.1.9037962.html) on where this expression comes from.